# What's the easiest way to piledrive everybody into the ice?

Tags: nhl-11

What are the different stats that control my on-ice performance?  What exactly does each stat control?  Stats like "Offensive Awareness" don't exactly clearly define what is going to be affected by adding points to them, while others like "Passing" are more obvious.

Comment: Edited title to correspond to my new mantra: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/122047#122047

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stats Breakdown: Where this quote is from](http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/15/1996120.page#7686847)

[Stat Calc](http://nhl11.atspace.com)

> - Deking: The higher the deking attribute is, the more effective loose
>     puck dekes become and the more
>     accurately players will be able to shoot
>     following a deke move.
> - Hand-eye: This attribute affects a player's deflections, batted pucks,
>     one-timers, and their ability to pick
>     up hard passes.
> - Off. Awareness: Players in possession of high offensive awareness
>     have good vision, which improves their
>     playmaking ability and a knack for
>     finding the back of the net.
> - Passing: The higher the passing attribute, the more accurate passes
>     become. The passing attribute also
>     affects the ability to make blind
>     passes and increases the chance they
>     will get passes through traffic as
>     well as making those passes easier to
>     control from the receiving player.
> - Puck Control: This attribute affects a player's ability to maintain control
>     of the puck through hits and stick
>     checks (i.e. poke checks and stick
>     lifts). Puck control also determines
>     whether or not one can do an on-knees
>     deke on the breakaway.
> - Shooting Accuracy: Wrist shot accuracy and slap shot accuracy
>     control how accurate these shots are.
> - Shooting Power: Wrist shot power and slap shot power control how hard a
>     player may shoot the puck.
> - Aggressiveness: This attribute gives a bonus to hitting intensity, a big
>     hit intimidates opponents and in
>     high-pressure situations, an
>     intimidated opponent will have reduced
>     shot quality, pass accuracy, and
>     reduced aggression.
> - Body Checking: This attribute gives the ability to deliver bigger body
>     checks. Checking also affects the
>     intensity of the hits delivered.
> - Def. Awareness: This attribute affects how much a player pays
>     attention to protecting the defensive
>     end of the ice. This includes better
>     ability to take away passing lanes,
>     lower susceptibility to being deked
>     and greater effort on the back check.
> - Discipline: The discipline attribute affects the likelihood of taking
>     penalties. For example, if a player
>     has higher discipline, they will be
>     less likely to get an elbow up on a
>     guy during a hit.
> - Faceoffs: The winner of a faceoff is determined by a number of factors
>     including this attribute which
>     influences the likelihood of winning
>     the faceoff.
> - Fighting Skill: Along with strength this attribute will affect punching
>     power.
> - Shot Blocking: Shot blocking affects the speed in which a player gets up
>     from a shot block, and the type of
>     block -- a diving block (on their
>     stomach) or a standing block (straight
>     up legs together). Players with a high
>     shot block attribute will be more
>     likely to do the diving shot block.
> - Stick Checking: This attribute affects both poke checks and stick
>     lifts in their ability to take the
>     puck successfully and to avoid taking
>     penalties while doing so.
> - Acceleration: This attribute affects how quickly a player reaches top
>     speed. If one has lots of
>     acceleration, the player will get to
>     their top speed faster than someone
>     who has less acceleration but lots of
>     top speed.
> - Agility: This attribute affects the ability to turn. The more agility, the
>     sharper one can turn with speed. This
>     also helps when cutting across the ice
>     while back skating on defense.
> - Balance: This affects a player's resistance from being knocked over on
>     a hit as well as their puck control.
>     The more balance one has, the better
>     they stay on their feet.
> - Durability: This attribute decreases the chance of injury. In EASHL
>     specifically, you can play through all
>     injuries but they will result in a
>     temporary attribute reduction to your
>     player never lasting beyond the end of
>     that game.
> - Endurance: This attribute will determine the rate at which the player
>     recovers energy when not skating with
>     high effort. Fatigue will play a
>     greater factor if a player has low
>     endurance. Fatigue affects both
>     skating ability and shooting.
> - Speed: This attribute affects a player's top speed. Note that a player
>     cannot sustain a top end speed without
>     high endurance.
> - Strength: This attribute is a modifier that affects shot power,
>     fighting, checking, resisting hits,
>     and boardplay. Strength will give
>     extra power in shots, punches and
>     hitting. Strength will also help with
>     resisting hits. Strength affects the
>     ability to pin players to the boards
>     while initiating boardplay, and the
>     ability to slip free when one is being
>     pinned in boardplay.